# Resolve hostname without FQDN

Tags: bind, hostname, internal-dns, nslookup

I'm trying to configure Bind for internal LAN usage only (Linux server, Windows clients) and I would like to resolve workstation both by fqdn and shortname.
For example, **without** DNS server, supposing to have a host named `host001` I'm able to do:

```
    nslookup host001
    ping host001
```

And it works. Using a DNS server I need to specify the FQDN:

```
    nslookup host001.example.com
    ping host001.example.com
```

Is there a way to enter a shortname in DNS so writing `host001` I obtain the resolve query of `host001.example.com`?

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I usually see this done is by having the DNS server resolve just the FQDN, but adding the domain to the search list in the DNS config on the clients. You can push this out to the clients via DHCP. I have two networks running in this way and it just works, with no issues on Windows, Linux, or Mac.

Comment: Hello Bart,
you are right, it's working correctly this way. 

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: This solutions seems somewhat inelegant.  I'm thinking of upgrading my dnsmasq install with master/slave bind9... I know in dnsmasq one can specify the domain and expand-hosts option to achieve the same thing without having to use dhcp to set a search domain.